# Gatling : condition to get a specific value from a JSON

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

I'm new to Gatling, and a bit struggling on this.

I have this JSON object coming from an HTML :

```
<div id="DATA--DECL-DATA">{"isCompany":false,"accommodations":[{"id":"00000000031000000067","isChecked":false,"name":"5 JULI 2017","addressLine1":"STRAAT 10 ","addressLine2":"1000 New York","nightsDeclared":0,"schoolNightsDeclared":0,"schoolNightsAttached":0,"taxableNights":0.0,"totalPayment":0.0,"isInProgress":false,"isLate":false,"isPayed":"false","deadline":"2021-12-31","initialAmount":0.0,"remainingAmount":0.0},{"id":"00000000031000006362","isChecked":false,"name":"BELLEVIE","addressLine1":"STRAAT 10 ","addressLine2":"1000 New York","isInProgress":false},{"id":"00000000031000006380","isChecked":false,"name":"BELLEVIE","addressLine1":"STRAAT 10 ","addressLine2":"1000 New York","isInProgress":true},{"id":"00000000031000006390","isChecked":false,"name":"BELLEVIE","addressLine1":"STRAAT 10 ","addressLine2":"1000 New York","isInProgress":true}]}</div>
```

Which if prettified, render this :

```
{
  "isCompany": false,
  "accommodations": [
    {
      "id": "00000000031000000067",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "5 JULI 2017",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": false
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006362",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "BELLEVIE",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York"
      "isInProgress": false
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006380",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "BELLEVIE",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": true
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006390",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "BELLEVIE",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": true
    }
  ]
}
```

To get this JSON Array from that div and save it into a session variable in Gatling, I wrote this "check" :

```
.check(css("div#DATA--DECL-DATA").saveAs("myJsonObj"))
```

And then to print the result in the console once the script is executed, I wrote this :

```
.exec { session => println("json = " + session("myJsonObj").as[String]); session }.exitHereIfFailed
```

This will print in the console, the full prettified JSON array that you saw above.

---

Now in that accommodations JSON Array we can see that there are severals ids when the **"isInProgress" is false**.

My question then is, how to do get the first id of an accommodation when that **"isInProgress" is false** ?

So : if "IsInProgress" is false => get the first accommodation id in that array.

Comment: What solutions have you tried and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I first tried to get the accommodation id in that array with a regex and it worked, .check(regex(""""accommodations":\[\{"id":"(.*?)"""").saveAs("accommodationId")). However it will always render the first accommodation id. The goal is to be able to get the first accommodation in that json array, when the "isInProgress" is false. So each time an id is submitted in the form, and that it turns the "isInProgress" to "true", it will get an existing id where "isInProgress" is "false".

Answer (score 0):

The following code is in Javascript, but should be easy to convert to scala.

```js
var json = {
  "isCompany": false,
  "accommodations": [
    {
      "id": "00000000031000000067",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "5 JULI 2017",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": false
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006362",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "BELLEVIE",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": false
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006380",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "BELLEVIE",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": true
    },
    {
      "id": "00000000031000006390",
      "isChecked": false,
      "name": "BELLEVIE",
      "addressLine1": "STRAAT 10 ",
      "addressLine2": "1000 New York",
      "isInProgress": true
    }
  ]
}

var FilteredJson = json.accommodations.filter((value) => {if (value.isInProgress === false) {return value}});

//just take the first value of FilteredJson

console.log(FilteredJson[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70436671/7512201) you need `check` with a json-path with condition:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.accommodations[?(@.isInProgress==false)].id").find.saveAs("id"))
```

Explanation:

`@.isInProgress==false` - it's a condition for each object inside array `accommodations`.
More details about json-path can be found [here](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-goessner-dispatch-jsonpath-00.html#name-jsonpath-examples)

Gatling's method `find` returns the first occurrence. Also exist method `findAll` which returns all values...

Comment: You've missed the "I have this JSON object coming from an HTML". If this information is correct, the payload is not JSON and you can't use jsonPath or jmesPath.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE Yes, but in another question I answered how to transform for work only with json
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70436671/7512201


I saw your answer, but I thought it was unnecessary to use Jackson...